# Can't we use foreign libraries while doing questions on codechef and other famous coding websites?

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.6

I was doing a question on codechef and got stuck on this problem : https://www.codechef.com/problems/TLG

In this problem we have to type a no. which will be the no. of testcases of the problem.Then we will have to type two more integers.These integers will take the
score of the players in "a b" format.At last the program will display the lead in the match in which the specific player had maximum lead and the player no.(i.e. 1 or 2).My program is this:

```
import operator
from operator import itemgetter
p = []
k = []
u = []

for r in range(int(input())):
    one,two = input().split()
    one = int(one)
    two = int(two)
    p.append((one,two))

for (one,two) in p:
    if (one)> (two):
        y = (one) - (two)
        m =1

    else:
        y = (two) - (one)
        m = 2

    k.append((m,y))

foo = k
foo.sort(key=lambda x:x[1])

h = foo[-1]

u.append(h)
b = list(map(operator.itemgetter(0), u))
r = list(map(operator.itemgetter(1), u))

print(b[0],r[0])
```

What is the problem in my program? The website showed that my answer is wrong.
Then i searched other submissions and found:

```
t = int(input())


p1 = 0
p2 = 0 
maxi = 0
leader = 1

for i in range(t):
    x,y = map(int,input().split())
    p1+=x
    p2+=y
    if abs(p1-p2) > maxi:
        leader = 1 if p1 > p2 else 2 
        maxi = abs(p1-p2)

print('{} {}'.format(leader,maxi))
```

I want to know how this program prints the maximum lead and the player.It doesn't use any array and sort function then how does it remember all the outputs and their values.

Comment: The trick with codechef / hackerrank / etc is to use smart code - most of the code fails not because the algorythm is wrong but because if applied to the datapoints is too either **too slow** or **too expensive** - sorting a list of 2000000 values takes time - iterating 2million values and remembering a maxvalue is _fast_. (this does not solve this riddle but servers as explanation...) - remembering all permutations for a..z is memoryexpensive. You need to find a more optimal algorythm to your solution so it does not time out nor break memory bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program has no need to store the input history.  All you need is the best result so far, that being the size of the lead and the player who held it.  You accumulate the score, round by round.  At the end of each round, you check to see whether the current lead is larger than the previous maximum.  If so, you update.

Your first problem is that you check the score differential in each round, rather than the accumulated score.  Your code happens to work for the given example, in which the maximum spread *happens* to be at the end of round 1.  You need to find the maximum *lead*, not merely the largest difference for a given round.

I expect that the problem is your overhead in storing all the scores and then *sorting* them all, is running you over the site's time limit.  You do *not* need a sorted list, merely the maximum value.